# Override Long Press Search button to show dialog

Tags: android, search, overriding, long-press

Ok, I've searched the questions/answers on stackoverflow and various sites around the web.
From what I've seen, people seem to think that it is impossible to override the long press search button to start an activity/dialog. This cannot be possible since handcent, a market app uses the long press search button to start a quickcompose activity.
Sadly, when I specify

< receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".musicdialog" >
        < intent-filter android:priority="1">
            < action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
        < /intent-filter>
    < /receiver>

I've also tried < action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />

some people have thought the long press search button uses global_search but I don't want to override that functionality.

Simple question. How do I Override Long Press Search button to show dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS` is an activity action. You use it with an `<activity>` in its `<intent-filter>`, not with a `<receiver>`.

Comment: i use
  <activity
   android:name=".panik"
   android:configChanges="orientation"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
   </intent-filter></activity>
 </application>
but it is not working...  is something wrong?

Comment: You also always need <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> in your intent-filter

Comment: Ugh, won't let me edit anymore.

You also always need `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` in your intent-filter. And the first `ACTION` doesn't need to be there. Should be       

`<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>`